# Rate Limit Gatling-grpc users outbound requests/second

Tags: java, grpc, load-testing, gatling, rate-limiting

Rate Limit Gatling-grpc users outbound requests/second
We are working on one a critical project and executing load tests using https://github.com/phiSgr/gatling-grpc framework targeting GRPC specific services. We are trying to limit the number of outbound requests from gatling GRPC user like only 1 req/sec. currently as part of our test, each of the GRPC user is making more than 500 reqs/sec.

As per Gatling documentation https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/scenario/ we could leverage pace for normal http requests like
forever().on(
pace(5)
.exec(
// will be run every 5 seconds, irrespective of what pause time is used
pause(1, 4)
)
);

Would be good to have this pace like method for gatling-grpc as well so as to limit our GRPC clients.

No clear workaround thought of currently. Is there any temporary workaround within gatling-grpc on how to limit the outbound requests/sec for GRPC users ?

tried to use the pace method within our gatling-grpc java client code.

Comment: I see no reason why the `pace` method wouldn't work alongside gRPC requests. "tried to use the pace method within our gatling-grpc java client code." Then post that code.

Comment: Which type of gRPC are you using there ? UNARY or STREAMING ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I consider this fixed like below, so to add a gatling pace to this Gatling GRPC. Basically, pass the `pace` to `forever.on()`

I am using this Gatling GRPC client:
https://github.com/phiSgr/gatling-grpc

```java
private final ScenarioBuilder myScenario =
    scenario("InboundGrpcScenario")
        .forever()
        .on(pace(6).exec(inboundHydration()));
```

The most helpful link was:
https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/scenario